# How do I install java, ant, and red5 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: java, red5

How do I install java, ant, and red5 on Ubuntu 14.04.
All I see is Ubuntu 12.04, which doesn't work. Redhat tutorials do not work.   UBUNTU 12.04 TUTORIALS DO NOT WORK!!!!

Answer (score 0):

http://linuxadminzone.com/quickly-install-java-ant-ivy-and-red5-flash-server-in-linux/ 
Google is your friend. It took 2 minutes to find the answer

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please edit your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: -1 Link is dead. I would actually downvote, but I'm also too lazy.  So I'll just criticize and not even bother ending this sentence with a period

Answer (score 0):

I found packages for all of them, so I assume just apt-get installing the packages should work:

```
sudo apt-get install ant openjdk-7-jdk red5-server libtomcat6-java icedtea-7-plugin
```

The command works for me. I have ubuntu 14.04, and on my system red5-server depends on :

```
shackle@shackle-desktop:~$ apt-cache depends red5-server
red5-server

Depends: adduser
 |Depends: default-jre-headless
  Depends: <java6-runtime-headless>
    openjdk-6-jre-headless
    default-jre-headless
    openjdk-7-jre-headless
    oracle-java6-installer
    oracle-java7-installer
    oracle-java8-installer
    oracle-java9-installer
    sun-java6-jre
  Depends: libred5-java
  Depends: libtomcat6-java
  Conflicts: <red5>
```

It includes libtomcat6-java but not libtomcat7-java.

The answers to [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) might be helpful.

Perhaps :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

to see list of held packages

```
sudo apt-get remove <packagesfromabove>
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then retry the command above.

Comment: Heres the output when I run that command. So no. Don't assume.................... Output:                                                                                        The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 red5-server : Depends: libtomcat7-java but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Setting up red5-server (1.0~svn4374-3) ...
 * Starting Flash streaming server  red5-server                          [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript red5-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package red5-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up icedtea-7-plugin:amd64 (1.5-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 red5-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Can you post the full set of commands and errors in your question so it can be formatted properly? Also check if there is a more detailed error message in /var/log/red5/error.log

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run the following commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

To install java:

```
   `java -version`
```

(If it returns "The program java can be found in the following packages", Java hasn't been installed yet, so execute the following command:)

`sudo apt-get install default-jre`

`sudo apt-get install default-jdk`

Reference [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

Install ant:

`sudo apt-get install ant`

To install red5:

`apt-get install -y red5-server`

(Here you may get some dependency problem like:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 red5-server : Depends: libtomcat6-java (>= 6.0.20-7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
) then use the command

`sudo apt-get install libtomcat6-java`

to start red5:

`service red5-server start`

refrence [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-red5-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: @WillShackleford let me know my answer is useful or not...if solved please accept it as answer =)

Answer (score 0):

this is  bug with Red5 in Ubuntu version 14.04 reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/red5/+bug/1312814). it is working with lower version. 
you can do manual installation that will work . i have tested it on Ubuntu 14.04.

For installation of red5 follow steps of my another answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/674879/432559)

other packages you can install with `apt-get`